# Populate list property with AutoPoco

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autopoco

I recently tried AutoPoco for c#, which is a tool to automatically create POCOs and fill them with test data. However, I'm stuck at the moment. I have a person POCO, and each person has a list of E-Mail addresses, like so:

```
class Person
{
    String Name;
    int Age;
    List<string> EmailAddresses;
}
```

Now I try to populate it with AutoPoco:

```
                x.Include<Person>()
                   .Setup(p => p.Name).Use<FirstNameSource>();
                   .Setup(p => p.EmailAddresses).Use<EmailAddressSource>()
                ;
```

But the second line fails with a syntax error, because it expects a string property, not a list. AutoPoco has an EnumerableSource which probably is what I need, however I couldn't find any code samples for it. Can you give me a hint on how to populate a string list with AutoPoco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. The code snippet you posted doesn't compile, so that was the first problem.

I couldn't find a more elegant way to generate the elements of the collection.

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name;
    public int Age;
    public List<string> EmailAddresses = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string email)
    {
        EmailAddresses.Add(email);
    }
}

[Test]
public void Noodling()
{
        IGenerationSessionFactory factory = AutoPocoContainer.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.Conventions(c => { 
            c.UseDefaultConventions();
        });
        x.AddFromAssemblyContainingType<LegacyUserProfileDto>();

        x.Include<Person>()
            .Setup(p => p.Name).Use<FirstNameSource>()
            .Invoke(z => z.Add(Use.Source<string, EmailAddressSource>()));
        //.Invoke(z => z.EmailAddresses.Add(Use.Source<string, EmailAddressSource>()));//Fails
    });
    IGenerationSession session = factory.CreateSession();

    Person person = session.Single<Person>().Get();
    Console.WriteLine(person.Age + " " + person.Name);
    foreach (string emailAddress in person.EmailAddresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emailAddress);    
    }
}
```